# Is it possible to easily move all commits from one branch onto another as one commit?

Tags: git, rebase, fixup

I know, I can do an interactive rebase, reword first commit and fixup all other. But if a branch contains hundreds of commits it becomes very tedious.

Is there a simpler way?

Comment: `git checkout -b <another-branch> && git reset --soft <first-commit-sha> && git commit`?

Comment: If you have a text editor with line numbers, then it should not so hard to identifies the rows which need to be changed and then do a mass replace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `git merge --squash` to squash the commits into a single one while merging into the branch.

Switch to the target branch

```
$ git checkout target-branch
```

then use

```
$ git merge --squash original-branch
```

All the commits in `original-branch` will be merged into a single one, and applied to the `target-branch`.

Comment: You will still need to do a `git commit` after the squash merge.

Answer (score 4):

You can do that with [`git cherry-pick -n`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick). That approach is more flexible compared to `git merge --squash` since it allows you to specify an arbitrary range of commits:

```
git cherry-pick -n OTHER_BRANCH~100..OTHER_BRANCH
git commit -m "Merged 100 commits from OTHER_BRANCH"
```

> **`git cherry-pick`**
>
> **`-n|--no-commit`**
>
> Usually the `git cherry-pick` command automatically creates a sequence
>   of commits. This flag applies the changes necessary to cherry-pick
>   each named commit to your working tree and the index, without making
>   any commit. In addition, when this option is used, your index does not
>   have to match the HEAD commit. The cherry-pick is done against the
>   beginning state of your index.
>
> This is useful when cherry-picking more than one commits' effect to
>   your index in a row.

Comment: Thanks for this useful option! It's really interesting. But I can't understand the last part of the last sentence: 'effect to your index in a row.' What it means?

Comment: @VictorDombrovsky That sentence can be rephrased as "This is useful when merging changes from multiple commits into the index".